# Python XML response parsing having nested tags

Tags: python, python-requests, xml-parsing

Have a response from backend api which is giving me the below response.I want to extract out the pid data "1664953412.79414"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" shp_request_proxied_from="3DB91F64-892E-4DB2-9271-C5CB5CAFBFBB">
    <title>jobs</title>
    <updated>2022-10-05T10:48:30-07:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Splunk</name>
    </author>
    <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
    <entry>
        <published>2022-10-05T00:03:34.000-07:00</published>
        <author>
            <name>abc-pull</name>
        </author>
        <content type="text/xml">
            <s:dict>
                <s:key name="pid">1664953412.79414</s:key>
            </s:dict>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I have tried various approaches but I am not able to extract out the data.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
pid = minidom.parseString(response.text).getElementsByTagName('pid')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

ThenI tried like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
print(root.tag)
print(root.find('entry'))
```

But not getting entry tag data also properly
Can someone please help here.
Note :- I cannot use xmltodict as thats not available in my enterprise packages

Answer (score 1):

Y ou can use `BeautifulSoup` to pull the text node value of  tag `s:key` along with attr `name="pid"`  because it's super powerful to parse `html and xml` DOM contents.

```
xml_doc = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" shp_request_proxied_from="3DB91F64-892E-4DB2-9271-C5CB5CAFBFBB">
    <title>jobs</title>
    <updated>2022-10-05T10:48:30-07:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Splunk</name>
    </author>
    <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
    <entry>
        <published>2022-10-05T00:03:34.000-07:00</published>
        <author>
            <name>abc-pull</name>
        </author>
        <content type="text/xml">
            <s:dict>
                <s:key name="pid">1664953412.79414</s:key>
            </s:dict>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pid = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'lxml').select_one('s\:key[name="pid"]').text
print(pid)
```

**Output:**

```
1664953412.79414
```

Comment: @Fazlul can this be done without BeautifulSoup

Comment: As it's pseudo-class ,so xml will not work here. I've tested

Comment: @pythonNinja Alternative is using xpath

Comment: ok so ElementTree cant bed used